# Want to copy SQL Database info and paste into new Activity

Tags: android, sql, copy-paste, duplicate-data

I have two activities. One that shows the user his Database info for a particular entry, and from there he can choose to edit that entry.

I want to add the feature of copying the existing data and starting a new entry with the old data so that you wont have to input all the same info again.

I have tried just using SharedPrefs but got nowhere. Hopefully someone here can shed some light on the proper coding etiquette.

I'll do my best to be very detailed in my description

This is the code to start a whole new entry.....

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
  Intent addContact = new Intent(CrList.this, CrAETune.class);
  startActivity(addContact);
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Then this class is where you edit the new entry and this is the code i'm using to save it...

```
     private void saveContact() 
       {
          CrDbCon dbConnector = new CrDbCon(this);

          if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
          {
              dbConnector.insertContact(
                      caret.getText().toString(),//1
                      lapet.getText().toString(),
                      trket.getText().toString());
```

This is the class where you view the entry, and subsequently can edit but need to be able to copy this into a new entry...

```
 case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, CrAETune.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CrList.ROW_IID, rowid);
            addEditContact.putExtra("car", car.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("lap", lap.getText());
  startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;
```

If this isnt enough info just let me know in the comments...I'm pretty lost here...not sure what to do to get my desired result. Thanks Ahead of time...

Comment: You could try `intent.getStringExtra("car")` in your new activity to get the value you put. Why SharedPrefs failed in your case though?

Comment: Well i used SP in the past but i coded it to automatically save as soon as you exited and then load upon return and of course in this case i need it to save and load upon a button click...which gave me problems...Just didnt get close to working from what i could tell.                                     So i would place the intent.getStringExtra("car") in the VIEW class and that would load the value into the new class upon arrival? Then the user would just save and move on...?

Answer (score 1):

Well the best way I think is to pass the contact id to your addContact activity. Then populate using that id, load all user data, and run it save it as a new item. (e.g. `dbconnection.addContact(..,..,contact,stuff..);`)

This would allow the person to make any changes they wanted to the contact or they could change nothing.

Comment: Where would i add this code? In the new addContact class? Sorry, i'm very newb with all this, everything i learn is here or online videos/tutorials...Just tryin to wrap my brain around this.

Comment: You can use the AddContact activity. (or you can subclass your edit contact activity since they should use the same layouts and most of the same logic). Inside the add contact activity go back into your database with that id and return all that contact info. Then populate your edit texts with the proper info. Then just click save like you would on a regular new contact, this should create a new id for it inside your database. Its maybe 10 lines of extra code to what your add contact activity should have now.

Comment: How do i grab the specific ID since each one is made automatically? Just ask for ROW_IID? If i'm understanding correctly, i was going down a similar path. I tried to make it so that when i hit "COPY" it opened the AddEdit class and populated the editTexts with the previous content. Problem was that when i hit save it was as if nothing had been changed and there was still only the one entry.

Comment: To be clear it is in fact opening the class and adding the text. Its just not saving it. As new or into the old one.

Comment: How are you populating the edit rows in the first place. The way I understood you is that you have a database. you get the contact out of the database and you want to save it into a new place right?

Comment: Yes, i populate them with user input. Then the user saves the info, the database uses auto increment and adds a row. What i want is for the user to be able to copy that row, change whatever they'd like and then when they hit save, it saves it as a new and separate entry. I'm going to try again with SharedPreferences tonight.